# jQuery - calculate element width through subtract pixel from window size

Tags: jquery, window, subtraction

My goal is to calculate the width of a fixed positioned element (top:0; left:200px;) through subtract 200px from the window size so that it fits the rest of the viewport. Therefore I used the following code but sadly it doesn't work. Hopefully someone of you guys can help me!

```
$(function() {
    width = ($(window).width() - 100);
    $("div").css("width", width);
})​;
```

Comment: Could you put together a http://jsfiddle.net showing what you're trying to do. It's no obvious from your description.

Comment: For sure, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/w555h/1/ Simplified, I will subtract the width of an element A from the window width to get the width of an element B.

Comment: There is a red dot on the last line of your Fiddle. If you remove it, it fixes your script (sort of).

Comment: Thanks for your support! Here's a new Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D2LDF/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to rely on jQuery, actually. There is a simply CSS trick to get this done, by declaring `right: 0` on that element. It forces it to stretch all the way to the right border of the viewport, naturally.

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
}
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/2Fhue/

**Update 1:** OP has provided his own fiddle, so here is the one with the fix applied: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/w555h/2/. I have also taken the liberty to remove `height: 100%` and use `bottom: 0` instead, which demonstrate the same concept as using positional coordinates to forcibly stretch the dimension of the element :)

**Update 2:** OP has requested a jQuery-based solution (beats me why, but anyway...), and here is how it works — we perform the width calculation within an anonymous function fired when the resize event is fired on the `$(window)` object. The second `.resize()` event is chained so that it fires upon DOM ready.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var width = $(this).width() - 200;
        $("#content").css("width", width);
    }).resize();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/w555h/4/

**Comment:** I typically try to avoid using jQuery (or JS) for purposes like this, when CSS can be easily used. That is because by calculating the width from that of the viewport, you will also have to listen to the `.resize()` event of the window, which complicates things.

Comment: I really need to get the width via jQuery since I will used for calculating my image gallery.

Comment: Now there's the next problem which needs to be solved.

Each image should have a 16:9 aspect ratio. Therefore, I have to divide the <li> width 16 and multiply this value with 9. Doesn't seem to be that hard but actually I am stuck.

Comment: @user2825956 That is beyond the original scope of this question - you should create a new question for this purpose.

Comment: OK, I will do! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I expanded on Terry's jQuery answer. I wouldn't typically code something like this, but I inherited a WordPress theme where the #secondary sidebar changes size dynamically, but only when the #main container > 768px. Goes without saying, #primary and #secondary are floated left ;-)

```
    $(window).resize(function(){

        var main = $("#main").width();
        var secondary;

        if (main > 768) {
            secondary = $("#secondary").outerWidth(true);
        } else 
            secondary = 0; // Ignore smaller dimensions where the sidebar is not visible.

        $("#primary").css("width", main - secondary - 1);

    }).resize();

    $(window).trigger('resize'); // When the page first loads
```